# cordovaで画像編集できるPluginまたはJSを教えて下さい。

Tags: javascript, jquery, onsen-ui, angularjs, cordova

タイトルの通りです。
cordova上で写真画像を編集できるPluginまたはJSを探しております。
以下の画像編集機能があるものが条件です。

1. 画像切り取り
2. ペンでのペインティング
3. スタンプ貼り付け
4. 画像のモザイク
5. 画像のタグ付け

もしご存知でしたらご教授ください。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score -1):

自己回答します。
img.lyの「Photo Editor SDK for HHTML5」を見つけて実装してみました。

切り取りや回転、フィルター等の機能がありある程度使えそうです。
またある程度のカスタマイズができるようです。

[詳細はこちら](https://www.photoeditorsdk.com/documentation/html5/getting-started)